Training a transformer CNN for image output from scratch
I'm trying to train a Transformer-CNN model from scratch. The Transformer model is comparable to that of the ViViT model 2. The CNN is taking the output of the second (temporal) transformer and is generating an image output. The input are video files. The goal is to output the moving object in those video files which is partly hidden in those videos.
My architecture (in Pytorch) is as follows (from input to output):

TubletEmbedding
Convolution PatchEmbedding (1 Conv3D layer)
Adding of CLS Token
Positional Encoding
(Spatial) TransformerEncoder Layer (dim=512, heads=8, layers=1)
Adding of CLS Token
Global average Pooling
(Temporal) TransformerEncoder Layer (dim=512, heads=8, layers=1)
Decoder Layer

Linear
ReLU
Dropout
BatchNorm1d
Unflatten
2x

ConvT2d
ReLU
Dropout
BatchNorm2d


ConvT2d
Tanh



I have got about 80.000 individual training videos. I use warm up learning for 20 epochs and then Cosine Annealing with Warm Restarts with AdamW optimizer. My Batch Size is 64. For training speed up (I only have one 4090) I use Mixed Precision Training and Gradient Accumulation. My criterion is MSE.

The model is actually converging pretty fast as can be seen above. The validation loss is very small in the end, but the output is not as desired. It is pretty much a mixture of all possible objects in one place:

Any ideas?
